Adding specific y axis to boxplots (placed in a vertical way)
I'm trying to plot values over time in boxplots. The boxplots seem to overlap each other and I can't set a locked y axis. If I plot the specific positions they bunch up and the boxes are massive. Positions given are mean to be in millions of years, so 2.5 million years.
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#default themesns.set_theme()

#Loading data setmy_data = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\tchat\OneDrive\Documents\UQAM_MS\Samples\Ratio\CSV\NbTa_ages_test.csv")

#see datasetprint(my_data)

#Check for non numerical datanon_numeric_columns = my_data.select_dtypes(exclude=[float,int]).columnsif len(non_numeric_columns) > 0:print(f"Non-numeric columns detected: {list(non_numeric_columns)}")my_data[non_numeric_columns]=my_data[non_numeric_columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

#Check for missing valuesif my_data.isnull().values.any():print("Missing values detected, filling with column means.")my_data = my_data.fillna(my_data.mean())

#Number of columns in the datasetnum_columns = len(my_data.columns)print(f"Number of columns: {num_columns}")

positions = [2.420, 2.458, 2.460, 2.461, 2.471, 2.472, 2.475, 2.476, 2.477, 2.478,2.480, 2.481, 2.482, 2.485, 2.5]

if len(positions) != num_columns:
    raise ValueError(f"The length of positions ({len(positions)}) does not match the number of columns in the data ({num_columns}).")

ax = my_data.boxplot(positions=positions, vert=False)

ax.set_ylim(2.4,2.5)

plt.grid(True, axis='y', which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth=0.5)plt.grid(True, axis='y', which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth=0.5)

plt.show()

I tried adding subplots as well, but it doesn't seem to work.
The boxplots that come out

Did you consider seaborn's boxplot? This would spread out the boxplots by default. Note that your post is missing reproducible test data.

you can change the widths of the boxes with the widths kwarg: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot
